# Does Angular httpClient construct an observer?

Tags: angular, observable

[httpsClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)
in angular is said to construct an observable, i am trying to grasp the notion of observable, so if it does construct an observable why should declare one? 
This confuses me because i have this project i am working on and the person that wrote the code used a service to get or post some data from the database (using http.get) and he subscribes to that

```
this.http.post('apihere','formhere',{
headers: new Httpheaders().set("content-type","application/json")
}).subscribe(data =>{//some stuff here})
```

Things i don't understand: Why didn't he declare an observer, Can i just use a service and subscribe without defining an observer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

As per the docs:

> HttpClient is available as an injectable class, with methods to perform HTTP requests. Each request method has multiple signatures, and the return type varies according to which signature is called (mainly the values of observe and responseType).

but if you look at Post method, it does return an observable of Object, HttpStream, ArrayBuffer etc .

You can just define your service method and subscribe to the same in your `component` class.
Ex:

Service class has

```
submitRequest(requestObj: any) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`my-url`, requestObj)
        .map(//do something);
}
```

In your component class just subscribe to your service:

```
myService.submitRequest(requestObj).subscribe( (response) => { 
  //do something with response 
});
```

Comment: Well Thank you, this helps to clear things out. So httpClient create an observable which i can subscribe to without me having to create it, so i should only create an observable when that function does not create an observable itself(like http)
so why people define observables when working with http is it just a good practice ?

Comment: you can subscribe to HttpClient methods if your service returns them as an observable. What do you mean by 'people define observables when working with http'? If you mean defining the return type of the service method, that's the practice to do and it helps us understand what kind of data is being returned and how your editor is going to help you when you refer to the data type returned.

Answer (score 1):

**First let's try and understand the difference between Observable and Observer:**

It seems that you're using the terms Observer and Observable interchangeably which I don't think would be a correct thing to do.

From this [**article from Todd Motto**](https://toddmotto.com/rxjs-observables-observers-operators#what-is-an-observer):

> **An Observable**: is just a function, with a few special characteristics. These are that it takes in an “observer” (an object with “`next`”, “`error`” and “`complete`” methods on it), and returns cancellation logic. In RxJS it would be a Subscription object with an unsubscribe method on it.
>
> **An observer** is the object literal that we pass into our `.subscribe()` (subscribe will invoke our Observable).

---

**Now let's see what the Angular StyleGuide has to say:**

Now that this confusion is cleared, let's talk about what the [**Angular's Style Guide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) say.

It emphasizes the [**Single Responsibility Principle**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility):

> Apply the single responsibility principle (SRP) to all components, services, and other symbols. This helps make the app cleaner, easier to read and maintain, and more testable.

The essence of the Single Responsibility Principle is that each and every piece of code that we write must be responsible for one and **JUST ONE** task.

**For a Component:** this would mean that the responsibility is to take user inputs and show the user some output. Now, what exactly does it show as an output and what exactly does it do of the input is not really it's responsibility.

**For a Service:** this would mean that the responsibility is just to get the input from the Component and do something with it. And it's responsibility is also to reach out to external sources and get the data the component needs to show on the view.

---

**Coming back to your example:**

Ideally whatever is received from any methods on the HttpClient is generally returned as is or after `map`ping to the Component. So `subscribe`ing right inside a Service method won't make much sense and should be considered as an anti-pattern.

So your Service can be refactored like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ...
  
  postData(formData) {
    return this.http.post('API', formData);
  } 
  
}
```

And this service can be used in your Component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  ...
  
  postData(formData) {
    this.dataService.postData(formData)
      .subscribe(response => /* DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESPONSE */);
  } 
  
}
```

---

**PS:** I'm not saying that it's wrong to `subscribe` to an `Observable`. All I'm suggesting that if the data is something that would be used as is in the component, the Observable should simply be returned from the Service method and should be `subscribe`d to in the Component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just subscribe.

From the docs here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html

> The Subscribe operator is the glue that connects an observer to an
>   Observable. In order for an observer to see the items being emitted by
>   an Observable, or to receive error or completed notifications from the
>   Observable, it must first subscribe to that Observable with this
>   operator.
>
> A typical implementation of the Subscribe operator may accept one to
>   three methods **(which then constitute the observer)**, or it may accept
>   an object (sometimes called an Observer or Subscriber) that implements
>   the interface which includes those three methods:

In this example:

```
this.productService.getProduct(id)
  .subscribe(
    (product: Product) => this.displayProduct(product),
    (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  );
```

The two methods passed into the subscribe constitute the observer.